# FutureBuilder causing error in DropDownButton after SetState

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dropdown, future

I have this:

```
List<Students> studentList= [];

Future<List<Students>> getJsonData() async {
   final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/students.json');
   final data =  await json.decode(response);
   studentList= await data.map<Sudents>((json) => Sudents.fromJson(json)).toList();
   return studentList;
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage ({super.key});
  @override
  State<TestPage > createState() => TestPage State();
}
class TestPage State extends State<TestPage > {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
           AppBar:...
           bottomNavigationBar:...
           body:FutureBuilder<List<Students>>(
              future: getJsonData() ,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                     case ConnectionState.waiting:
                        return const Center(child: Text("waiting"),);
                     default:
                        if(snapshot.hasError == false){
                             return BuildPage();                             
                        }
                 }
           )
         )
  }
```

Inside BuildaPage I have a dropdownlist.
When I select one element in this dropdown I call setState() to update.
I need to call the setState becaus when I select one item I need to set a Contorller' textfield.

So here is the problem. First I receive a redpage error saying that or are null or repeated itemns in this dropdown...

"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'Models'.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"

Second is calling again the getJsonData(). I dont need to update this json, I only need to read.

I am using the FutureBuilder to only start draw the dropdown only after all data was read.

Maybe I have repeated items because i am calling again getJsonData()?

Because null I guess no because the item are listed in dropdown. The problem only happens when I select one item.

Thank you for your support.

I tried without FutureBuilder but the problem is that I am reading an empty list bacause json wasn't ready in time when dropdown is reading the list.

EDIT1: One think that solve but I think that isnt correct is that I created a bool started = false; and in the getJsonData() I put one if/else. So if started equal true I dont read again the json. I only return the same list...But the question is and if I decide to create a dyanmic list and need to read again the list, so I will get the error!

EDIT2: Another test. Inside the getJsonData() I remove the if/else and in the beggining I put modelsListLoaded.clear(); but not worked. The same error. I tried to clear the list before but the same error happens.

EDIT3: if I remove all the FutureBuilder stuff and use this code:

```
@override
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
     getJsonData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Working very fine but only in emulator. In my mobile doesnt working because the dropdown remain disable because there are no items inside. But in emulator is working fine. After some seconds the dropdown change from disable to enable alone!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the studentList variable to be inside the TestPageState class.

Then update it in your getJsonData method inside of a setState() block.  For example:

```
  void getJsonData() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/students.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    final newStudentList = await data.map<Students>((json) => Students.fromJson(json)).toList();
    setState( () {
      studentList = newStudentList ;
    });
  }
```

Updating studentList within the setState call will result in the build() method being called again and it will use the new value that you assigned to the studentList.